# AWS Serverless + Cloud Formation: Error on single function deploy - Windows 10 Env

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I have a problem regarding the deploy in `AWS` of a single function using `Serverless` and `Cloud Formation`. I am using `Windows 10 - 64 bit` as OS.

Env:

```
 Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          win32
     Node Version:              10.16.3
     Framework Version:         1.52.1
     Plugin Version:            3.0.0
     SDK Version:               2.1.1
```

Basically, when I run the classical deploy of all my AWS env (`sls deploy -s dev`), everything works just fine. But when I try to deploy a single Lambda Function, on which I have changes, using this command:

```
sls deploy function -f MyLambdaFunc -s dev
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'artifact' of undefined
      at ServerlessPythonRequirements.BbPromise.bind.then.then.then (C:\Users\user\Documents\company\client\AWS_environment\deployment\node_modules\serverless-python-requirements\index.js:176:48)
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.invoke (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:505:22)
      at getHooks.reduce.then (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:540:24)
  From previous event:
      at PluginManager.run (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:540:8)
      at variables.populateService.then (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\Serverless.js:115:33)
      at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
      at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
      at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
  From previous event:
      at Serverless.run (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\lib\Serverless.js:102:74)
      at serverless.init.then (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\bin\serverless.js:67:28)
      at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:136:16
      at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:57:14
      at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
  From previous event:
      at initializeErrorReporter.then (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\bin\serverless.js:67:6)
      at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
      at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
      at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
  From previous event:
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serverless\bin\serverless.js:53:39)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
      at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
      at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
      at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Someone knows why? Maybe is there something wrong with my `npm` installation on `Windows 10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered that there are problems with the new version of Serverless (from `1.52`), and so users are unable to deploy single lambda function.

Basically there are no solutions for the problem now, except doing a rollback to the `1.51` version.

Here some details:

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/6752

Answer (score 1):

Update your function in `serverless.yml`:

```
your_function:
  # ...
  package: {}
```

Then `sls deploy` and `sls deploy function -f your_function`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround but I'm not sure about the side effects.

The problem is the following line (line # 176 in my version) in serverless-python-requirements/index.js file:

```
arguments[1].functionObj && 
    arguments[1].functionObj.package.artifact.
```

It simply assumes the existence of package.artifact path in your function definition in serverless.yml.

As a work around I added "package: artifact:" to my function as follows and it worked:

```
hello:
    handler: hello.handler
    package:
      artifact:
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
```

Again, I'm not sure if this breaks anything else. I have just tried an individual function deployment and it worked. But I didn't make a detailed test.